# Load a smart card minidriver without injecting a card

Tags: winapi, driver, smartphone, smartcard, cryptoapi

I am currently evaluating if it is possible to use a smart card minidriver for my project. My Project is to use a smartphone as a card reader and use it for a smart card login. What I'd like to know is if it is possible to make the Microsoft Base CSP load the smart card minidriver without the card beeing inserted into any actual card reader connected via USB. The idea is to either write a new csp or write a smart card minidriver to talk to the smart card over the smartphone. To achieve this I implement the communication between CSP or smart card minidriver via a simple TCP network connection or a bluetooth connection. Anyhow, in both cases I would need to CSP to load the driver without the card beeing inserted. Does any one have an idea how this can be acchieved?

Just for the record, I am using Windows 7 as the targeted platform.

Comment: Re-read minidriver spec about discovery.